# Javascript template doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I am making my first backbone web app, and i'm having some trouble getting the templates right. Right now 1 of my templates gives me exactly what i want from it, but the second doesn't show me anything.

The data i want to show is a menu bar with the country's where youtube provides services. The data comes from the youtube v3 i18nRegions api.

the JS file that triggers the template:

```
site.views.ContinentLinks = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        events: {'click a': 'clickHandler'},
        templatemenuitems: _.template(site.settings.templates.menuitems),
        templateError: _.template(site.settings.templates.error),
        initialize: function (prop) {
            console.log("starting continentlinks.js");
            console.log(prop);
            this.router = prop.router;
            this.loadMenuItems();
            console.log("started loading");
            site.events.trigger('newMenu');
        },
        clickHandler: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var curTarget = $(e.currentTarget);
            var curURL = 'videos/' + curTarget.data('country');
            console.log(curURL);
            this.router.navigate(curURL, {trigger: true, replace: true});
        }
        ,
        loadMenuItems: function () {
            console.log("started loadMenuItems");
            console.log(this.collection.url);
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: _.bind(this.loadMenuItemsSuccessHandler, this),
                error: _.bind(this.loadMenuItemsErrorHandler, this)
            });
        },
        /**
        *
        * @param collection
        * @param response
        */
        loadMenuItemsSuccessHandler: function (collection, response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            console.dir();
            this.$el.html(this.templatemenuitems({menuitems: response}));
            console.log("succesfull loaded menu");

        },
        /**
        * if the get call fails
        * @param collection
        * @param response
        */
        loadMenuItemsErrorHandler: function (collection, response) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            this.$el.html(this.templateError({message: data.error}));
        }
    });
```

and the template it self:

```
<% _.each(menuitems.items, function(Menuitem, index, list){%>
<a href="#" data-country="<% Menuitem.gl %>"><% Menuitem.name%></a>
<%}) %>
```

i have a link to current build of my webapp here: http://student.cmi.hro.nl/0876538/Jaar2/FED/Weindopdracht/

And the full code on github:
https://github.com/FlashDog123/FED01-Eindopdracht

Comment: Is your `el` attached to the DOM?

Comment: Which one works and which one doesn't?

Comment: @Mathletics The template on the bottom. the second template is for the videos. for that: http://student.cmi.hro.nl/0876538/Jaar2/FED/Weindopdracht/videos/us

Comment: @Jack i believe so, since i linked both templates the same way, and 1 of the 2 is working....

Comment: @JustinVeenis by bottom you mean your error template?

Comment: Not strictly related to the problem but considering the size of your application it's already overly complex. You have two views but tracking down a simple problem like this is already problematic. Take a look at these great examples: https://backbonetutorials.com/. Cheers!

Comment: @Jack No, the bottom code is the template that doesnt what i think it should show: for each item form the api a link...

Comment: @akoskm Stripping out unrelated code is the best way to find the problem. Yours is probably the most relevant comment.